# Controlling the reactor execution for certain use cases (or get response at certain point)

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I am trying to update a document in MongoDB but cannot get to checking updated status and responding back to user. Below is my code:

```
@Autowired
ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public Mono<String> updateUser(UserIn userIn) {
   UserResponse resp = new UserResponse();
   mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, User.class)
        //.doOnSuccess(bsItem -> {
        .flatMap(user -> {
            if(user.getItemId().equals(userIn.getId("_id")))
                resp.setStatus("Updated");
            else
                resp.setStatus("Failed");
            return Mono.just(resp);
   }).subscribe();

return Mono.just(resp.getStatus());
}
```

Even though update is happening in mongodb, it throws NPE while returning. How to get the control after reactor operator is executed here?

Comment: Dont subscribe in your application. You are not the subscriber, the calling client is the subscriber.

Comment: and what is sample.getStatus() and you havnt told exactly what it is that is throwing the null pointer. Is it findAndModify, is it sample.getStatus

Comment: Null pointer is thrown in sample.getStatus() when returning from the method. sample.setStatus() is invoked based on the updated status. Also, to answer your first comment, rest controller calls this updateUser() method, hence subscribed here.

Comment: And what is sample?

Comment: sorry my bad. edited the question now. It is UserResponse.

Comment: thank you now i can answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should almost never subscribe in your own application.

The subscriber is the client that initiated the call in this case it is probably the web application. You application is just relaying the data, so your application is a publisher which means you should not subscribe. The web app subscribes.

Try this.

```
@Autowired
ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public Mono<String> updateUser(UserIn userIn) {
    return mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, User.class)
        .flatMap(user -> {
            final UserResponse resp = new UserResponse();
            if(user.getItemId().equals(userIn.getId("_id")))
                resp.setStatus("Updated");
            else
                resp.setStatus("Failed");
            return Mono.just(resp.getStatus());
   });
}
```

A mono is not like a stream, you fetch, map and return, all in the same mono, like a chain of events. An event chain.

Comment: Thanks. It worked now after moving subscribing to client.